# The vector of random integers cannot be printed, C++

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote a simple program to generate a vector of random numbers. I tried to print each element in the vector but the output doesn't seem correct. For example, I push_back 5 numbers but the vector.size() gives 10... I have no idea why. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> arr(5);
    int i, val;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        val = rand()%30;
        cout << "value " << i << " is " << val << endl;
        arr.push_back(val);
    }

    for (i=0; i<arr.size() ; i++){
    cout << arr[i] << " " << arr.size() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

OUTPUT:
value 0 is 2
value 1 is 13
value 2 is 9
value 3 is 28
value 4 is 27
0 10
0 10
0 10
0 10
0 10
2 10
13 10
9 10
28 10
27 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line

```
vector<int> arr(5);
```

you already allocated 5 entries. You can access them without pushing back new elements. eg:

```
vector<int> arr(5);
arr[1];
```

is valid and won't crash.

Now if you do additional `push_back` you will extend existing vector, so it will change its size.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<int> arr(5);
```

This creates a vector of 5 elements.

```
arr.push_back(val);
```

This *appends* one new element to the vector. So the first time it is called, the vector will now contain 6 elements.

Answer (score 2):

The [vector constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) you are using, creates a vector with 5 values (equal to 0) already present in it. If you want to make the vector allocate space for 5 elements (as I am assuming - your plan). You can create a vector with a default constructor and then use the [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) method.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
vector<int> arr(5);
```

It should read

```
vector<int> arr; 
arr.reserve(5);
```